# How to get all data from both core in SOLR joins

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I have 2 core in Solr - Hotel and City. I want to do join operation on it so that I get all data from hotel as well as city.
I am using the query as

```
    http://localhost:8080/solr/hotel/select?q=*:*&fq={!join%20fromIndex=city%20from=id%20to=id}id:200709062148134302
```

In result I am getting data only from hotel core not from city core.

is there an way to get data from both core??
please suggest...

Answer (score 1):

No. Solr joins are comparable to `INNER JOIN` in SQL, as shown in [the example from the Solr Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join):

```
SELECT xxx, yyy
FROM collection1
WHERE outer_id IN (SELECT inner_id FROM collection1 where zzz = "vvv")
```

Comment: Yeah that's what the problem, my requirement it to get data from both core/table which seems no possibility...

Comment: Nope. Index everything into a single core (with city-information in each hotel document) or retrieve the city information from a different source.

Comment: It was same earlier hotel was having city information, but now requirement is like we need to remove city info and create city as separate schema.